# How do I color edges on a graph using a pattern?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I have the following code, an attempt to color the even branches of a tree... but it’s not working correctly:

`CompleteKaryTree[3,EdgeStyle->{_<->_?EvenQ ->Green},EdgeLabels->"Name"]`

[image: tree graph]

It’s coloring the 2<->5 edge whilst I thought it would only color the edges which ended in an even number?! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CompleteKaryTree[3, EdgeStyle -> {e_?( EvenQ[#[[2]]]&)-> Green}, EdgeLabels -> "Name"]
```

or

```
CompleteKaryTree[3, EdgeStyle -> {e_/;EvenQ[e[[2]]]-> Green}, EdgeLabels -> "Name"]
```

or

```
CompleteKaryTree[3, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeStyle -> {DirectedEdge[_, _?EvenQ] -> Green}, 
 EdgeLabels -> "Name", EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line"]
```

or

```
 CompleteKaryTree[3, 
 EdgeStyle -> {UndirectedEdge[a__] /; EvenQ[Max[{a}]]-> Green}, EdgeLabels -> "Name"]
```

all give

[image]

**Note:** The last one works with `CompleteKaryTree`; it doesn't work in general (thanks: Szabolcs).

Comment: Cool... anyway I can add Green for Odd and Red for even?

Comment: @CuriousDudeFromEgypt, try `CompleteKaryTree[3, 
 EdgeStyle -> {_ -> Green, e_?(EvenQ[#[[2]]] &) -> Red}, 
 EdgeLabels -> "Name"]`

Comment: `2<->5` has an even one too, and it's not coloured.

Comment: @Szabolcs, OP  wants: _"only color the edges which ended in an even number"_.

Comment: But undirected edges do not have an endpoint, nor is there any guarantee about what ordering they may show up with in a given context. Also, in OP's example `2<->5` is green. @CuriousDudeFromEgypt should clarify.

Comment: @Szabolcs, good point re ordering not working in general. I added a note. Re " in OP's example 2<->5 is green"; that's right, but my reading of the question was that CuriousDude does not want that. I think based on  the fact that `Cases[EdgeList[CompleteKaryTree[3]],_<->_?EvenQ, All]` gives
`{1<->2,2<->4,3<->6}` (similarly,
`{#,MatchQ[_<->_?EvenQ]@#}&/@EdgeList[CompleteKaryTree[3]]` gives
`{{1<->2,True},{1<->3,False},{2<->4,True},{2<->5,False},{3<->6,True},{3<->7,False}} `) one is lead to expect `EdgeStyle->{v1_<-> v2_?EvenQ ->Green}` to color an edge `Green` only when `v2` is even.